# Select the root document from inside a secound level iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, shadowbox

I'm trying to capture where the user clicks on the hole page but from an iframe inside an iframe.

so basically I can control where the user clicks on the 1st iframe from the 2nd iframe, but can't control where he clicks on the root document.

I've tried nearly everything and can't find an answer.

Here is my actuall javascript:

```
$(window, window.parent.document).document.click(function( event ) {
    alert(event.target.nodeName );
});
```

for context, I'm using shadowbox as iframes and my objective is to control when a user clicks outside of the shadowboxes

Comment: And the content of all three documents - parent page, and documents inside the nested iframes - is loaded from the same origin ...?

Comment: @CBroe Yes all from same domain, i have access to all 3 files

Comment: `$(window).document` in itself already returns undefined, you would need to de-reference the jQuery object first to get the "DOM version" of window, `$(window)[0].document`. Can't you just simply use `$(parent.document, top.document).click()`? That seems to be the most straight forward way to me

Comment: @CBroe So, I've tried : `$(parent.document, top.document).click()` but it only gets elements from the parent iframe, not from the root document.

Comment: `parent.parent.document`? If that's not it either, then please prepare a proper [mcve] for us to check/experiment with.

Comment: WOW... that actually did the trick... I've tried over 100 combinations on JQuery with window, parent, document and top. and it was that simple... I'm so dumm. Thx a Million. Please Write it as an answer and i'll validate it! thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(window).document` in itself already returns undefined, you would need to de-reference the jQuery object first to get the "DOM version" of window, `$(window)[0].document`

But turns out you can simply use `$(parent.document, parent.parent.document).click()`
That also kinda seems to be the most straight forward way to me.

(Don't know why `top.document` did not work, because that is always the topmost window instance, so from within an iframe-inside-iframe that should be the same as `parent.parent.document` ... or are there even more (i)frames involved, another level? Anyway, as long as you got something that works it doesn't really matter.)